# Which voltage should I use with a component that allows between 3v and 5.5v?

Tags: sensors, voltage-level, temperature-sensor, ds18b20

I have a DS18B20 temperature sensor that needs between 3v and 5.5v to work, as seen in its documentation.

What's the difference? Should it work better which 5.5v?

I know that a LED with more voltage will bright more but it will burn or a pump with more voltage will take water faster.  But what about the temperature sensor?

[image: DS18B20 temperature sensor]

Comment: what do you mean by `difference`?  it will properly at any voltage between 3V and 5.5V.  the output is digital, not analog

Comment: You should use the voltage that matches your hardware.  What sort of Arduino are you using?

Comment: I have an Arduinon Uno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the datasheet the absolute maximum is -0.5 V to 6.0 V.

The normal voltage for which it works according to the specifications in the datasheet is 3.0 V to 5.5 V.

That means het DS18B20 works well with 3.3 V and just as well with 5.0 V. One voltage is not "better" than the other. There is not difference. You can use it with a 3.3 V Arduino board and with a 5 V Arduino board.

The power it uses when being active is 1 mA * 5.0 V = 5 mW. It is possible that it causes some self-heating. But let's not go there. That is something for nerds.

Answer (score 2):

When a sensor like this allows a range of power supply voltages it's not because one voltage is "better" than another. It's purely to allow it to work with a wider range of controllers.

The voltage you would use it with is more dictated by what it is you are using it with. If you are using it with a 5V microcontroller, such as the Arduino Uno then you would run the sensor at 5V, since that is the logic levels your MCU will be working at.  If you are using it with a 3.3V microcontroller, such as a Teensy, Due, or chipKIT board, then you would run the sensor at 3.3V to maintain the right logic levels for the board you are using.

By running both the MCU and the sensor at the same voltage you remove the need for any logic level translation between the two.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing for a measurement module. You can use the 5V of the arduino, but with a resistance of 4.7KΩ between "Data" and "5V".

Like this example [image]